# Can 'Breakability' be Turned Off After Purchasing?

Tags: stair-dismount

The most recent update for Stair Dismount on ios introduces 'breakability' which enables your hapless dummies to fall apart.  If I buy this add-on, will I be able to toggle it on and off whenever I like?  I don't want it if it's permanent, and irreversible.

Comment: People pay for the strangest things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, buying will enable a checkbox which you can use to toggle it on/off.

Comment: Straight from the horse's mouth.